# use ocamlformat with cppo and dune

Tags: ocaml, ocaml-dune

to make our code work with multiple ocamlgraph versions, we are using this snippet in [one of our files](https://gitlab.com/irill/dose3/-/blob/ba90e8496c2958643f4872b01481d3be6d77522e/src/algo/dominators.ml)

```
#if OCAMLGRAPH_VERSION >= (2,0,0)
  let module Dom = Dominator.Make_graph(struct
      include G
      let empty () = create ()
      let add_edge g v1 v2 = add_edge g v1 v2; g
    end) in
#elif OCAMLGRAPH_VERSION >= (1,8,6)
  let module Dom = Dominator.Make_graph(G) in
#else
  let module Dom = Dominator.Make(G) in
#endif
```

And in our `dune` file we preprocess this with cppo like this:

```lisp
(library
 [...]
 (preprocess (action (run %{bin:cppo} -V OCAMLGRAPH:%{read:ocamlgraph.version} %{input-file})))

(rule
 (target ocamlgraph.version)
 (action (with-stdout-to %{target} (run ocamlfind query -format %v ocamlgraph))))
```

Now we want to use `dune build @fmt`. The problem is, that ocamlformat doesn't understand files that have yet to be preprocessed. One workaround would be to add the affected file to `.ocamlformat-ignore` but the file is rather large so it would be a pity to not have it auto-formatted.

Is there an easy solution to this problem? Maybe there is a common pattern how this can be solved with dune?

Answer (score 1):

Technically not an answer, but several leads:

- You could move the part that is preprocessed into antother file `dom.ml` and give up on formatting for this file which would than be small. Not ideal i know.
- Maybe you can take a look at Dune's [Alternative dependencies](https://dune.readthedocs.io/en/stable/concepts.html?highlight=alternative%20depend#alternative-deps) which allow you to select a module among different ones according to the presence or absence of a given library. But as far as i know, you still can't choose according to the version of some library, [see this issue](https://github.com/ocaml/dune/issues/397).
- You can use a mix of Makefile+Dune, have the pre-processing part handled by makefile and the formatting by dune.
- You could also use a first class module, but I suppose this is not satisfactory as you want the choice being made at compile time, and not at runtime.